# Perl reg expression to match end of string doesnt work

Tags: regex, perl

Not sure what is wrong in my perl script. unable to match the end of line using regular expression

```
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 SISPortal]$ forever logs
info:    Logs for running Forever processes
data:        script logfile
data:    [0] server /home/rmdev01/.forever/WusC.log
data:    [1] Server /home/rmdev01/.forever/2hai.log
```

script:

```
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 SISPortal]$ cat forever.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl

@logs=`forever logs`;

chomp(@logs);

foreach my $log (@logs)
{
        print "checking log at end of string $log\n";
        if ($log =~ /log$/)
        {
                print "$log\n";
        }
}
```

Output of script:

```
[rmdev01@inches-rmdev01 SISPortal]$ ./forever.pl
checking log at end of string info:    Logs for running Forever processes
checking log at end of string data:        script logfile
checking log at end of string data:    [0] server /home/rmdev01/.forever/WusC.log
checking log at end of string data:    [1] Server /home/rmdev01/.forever/2hai.log
```

Comment: Could there be whitespace before the linebreak? Try `/log\s*$/` and see if the error persists.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: it worked. but why there is whitespace even after chomp.

Comment: As far as I know, `chomp()` only removes newlines, but no other whitespace characters.

Comment: Specifically, `chomp` removes the value of `$/`, which is a line feed by default.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that there are some space/tab characters before the end of the string (`chomp()` only removes newlines, but no other whitespace characters).

Allow those trailing whitespace characters (and perhaps avoid matches like `Blog` by using a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)):

```
if ($log =~ /\blog\s*$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

`chomp` only removes a line feed<sup>[1]</sup>, while you apparently have other trailing whitespace (such as a carriage return).

`s/\s+\z//` removes all trailing whitespace, so it's using that is usually a better pratice than using `chomp`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

for (`forever logs`) {
    s/\s+\n//;
    print if /log$/;   # Or /\blog$/ as Tim Pietzcker suggested.
}
```

---

1. Technically, whatever the value of `$/` is. But `$/` start off containing a line feed.